# getter for a boolean array[][]

Tags: java, project

I basiically wrote a boolean array[x][y], x,y being the coordinates, if its true there is a bomb.

Im having trouble with the getter,

I have so far

```
boolean[][] bombArray = new boolean[Total_Columns][10];

for(x=0,x<Total_Colmns,x++){
    bombArray[x][0] = true;
    }

public boolean getBombArray(int x,int y){
   if(bombArray[x][y] .equals(true){
   return true;
   }
   else{
   return false;
   }
}
```

my main looks like this

```
main()
boolean isBomb = myPanel.getBombArray(x,y) //x and y being the cursor coordinates
if(isBomb){
....
.... 
....
....
{
else{
....
.... 
....
}
```

basically the grid is going to be like this

```
*********
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
```

but my get is not working, it keeps throwing exceptions

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: Just a note: there's no reason to use the conditions in the getBombArray, simply return the value at that location: `return bombArray[x][y];`

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if(bombArray[x][y] .equals(true){
```

is missing a closing parenthesis before the brace.

A correct version of your function would be:

```
public boolean getBombArray(int x,int y){
   // bombArray[x][y] has type 'boolean', which isn't an object, it's a primitive
   // (don't use .equals() on primitives)
   if(bombArray[x][y] == true){
       return true;
   } else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

But you can simplify this pretty significantly to something I think is a little clearer:

```
public boolean getBombArray(int x,int y){
   // bombArray[x][y] is true if there's a bomb, false otherwise
   return bombArray[x][y];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be getting a compile time error due to a missing parentheses here:

```
if(bombArray[x][y] .equals(true)
    ...
```

The whole function body should be:

```
 return bombArray[x][y];
```

Comment: Also, a `boolean` doesn't have a `.equals` function (a `Boolean` does, though)

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions happen at run time. I doubt this code is able to throw exceptions as it doesn't compile. Let's go through it:

```
for(x=0,x<Total_Colmns,x++){
    bombArray[x][0] = true;
}
```

To match your array declaration you want `Total_Columns` here rather than `Total_Colmns`. The commas should be semi-colons, and the x variable is possibly undeclared. Your loop should look like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Total_Columns; x++) {
    bombArray[x][0] = true;
}
```

Also, if you haven't copied-and-pasted separate snippets of code into your question, it seems like your loop is outside of any method. It won't work there. It probably belongs in your class's constructor.

In the getter you have:

```
if(bombArray[x][y] .equals(true){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

A `boolean` is a primitive type, not an `Object`, so it does not have an `equals` method. You can just use `bombArray[x][y] == true`. You're also missing a closing `)` on the `if` statement. Actually, since your array element is already a boolean you can just return it directly:

```
public boolean getBombArray(int x, int y) {
    return bombArray[x][y];
}
```

If you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s from passing in the cursor position, you might want to restrict the x & y coordinates in your getter. Something like:

```
if (x < 0 || x >= bombArray.length || y < 0 || y >= bombArray[x].length) return false;
```

If you're still getting errors and exceptions, show the real error messages. They contain the information to help you fix them. "not working" isn't enough information.

Comment: thanks now its working with no exceptions, but its always acting like if isBomb=false, i can post my code to see if you can help me find some kind of error?

Comment: public boolean getBombArray(int x,int y) {
  if(x < 0 || x > TOTAL_COLUMNS - 1 || y < 0 || y >     TOTAL_ROWS - 2){
   return false;
  }
  else{
   return bombArray[x][y];
  }
  
 }

Comment: @user2896762 I'd suggest printing out all the x & y that you're reading to make sure those are correct. Are you dividing the "cursor position" by the size of each grid square?